# Regular expressions: find string without substring

Tags: regex

I have a big text:

```
"Big piece of text. This sentence includes 'regexp' word. And this
sentence doesn't include that word"
```

I need to find substring that starts by '**this**' and ends by '**word**' but **doesn't** include word '**regexp**'.

In this case the string: "`this sentence doesn't include that word`" is exactly what I want to receive.

How can I do this via Regular Expressions?

Comment: Your rules are confusing or you have made a mistake with your expected output. Why no "And" and why no "Big piece of text."

Comment: @sjakubowski "substring starts by 'this' and ends by 'word'"

Comment: This rules are confusing but correct. I spent a lot of time to find something in google but found nothing.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

With an ignore case option, the following should work:

```
\bthis\b(?:(?!\bregexp\b).)*?\bword\b
```

Example: http://www.rubular.com/r/g6tYcOy8IT

Explanation:

```
\bthis\b           # match the word 'this', \b is for word boundaries
(?:                # start group, repeated zero or more times, as few as possible
   (?!\bregexp\b)    # fail if 'regexp' can be matched (negative lookahead)
   .                 # match any single character
)*?                # end group
\bword\b           # match 'word'
```

The `\b` surrounding each word makes sure that you aren't matching on substrings, like matching the 'this' in 'thistle', or the 'word' in 'wordy'.

This works by checking at each character between your start word and your end word to make sure that the excluded word doesn't occur.

Comment: +1 for the good explanation of the regex and the link to play with it - I was able to apply this to something similar and would have struggled without the explanation. I get fed up with answers that just give a bit of code without saying how it works.

Comment: You helped me a lot! Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Use lookahead asseterions.

When you want to check if a string does not contain another substring, you can write:

```
/^(?!.*substring)/
```

You must check also the beginning and the end of line for `this` and `word`:

```
/^this(?!.*substring).*word$/
```

Another problem here is that you don't want to find strings, you want to find sentences (if I understand your task right).

So the solution looks like this:

```
perl -e '
  local $/;
  $_=<>;
  while($_ =~ /(.*?[.])/g) { 
    $s=$1;
    print $s if $s =~ /^this(?!.*substring).*word[.]$/
  };'
```

Example of usage:

```
$ cat 1.pl
local $/;
$_=<>;
while($_ =~ /(.*?[.])/g) {
    $s=$1;
    print $s if $s =~ /^\s*this(?!.*regexp).*word[.]/i;
};

$ cat 1.txt
This sentence has the "regexp" word. This sentence doesn't have the word. This sentence does have the "regexp" word again.

$ cat 1.txt | perl 1.pl 
 This sentence doesn't have the word.
```

Comment: That lookahead alone won't do the job; you need to use nested lookaheads. And the code snippet that follows is rather hard to read (I don't know Perl) with no explanation. :/

Comment: @DragoonWraith: what are you talking about? This soultion does solve the task. You can try it yourself.

Comment: I tried the RegEx posted and it did not do so. `(?!` will prevent it from matching any case where the substring appears after `this` (from the example), even if the substring appears after `word`. Using a nested `(?:(?!` per F.J's answer fixes this. I don't have Perl available to test that snippet, but I'm not learning anything by looking at it, and from what I *can* tell it's not a RegEx solution anyway, since it appears to be manually walking through the string with that `while` loop. The question's tagged `regex` not `perl`.

Comment: @DragoonWraith: "even if the substring appears after word." it can't appear after word, because bowrd it the last part of the string

Comment: Oh, I understand the confusion now. You're taking the example test case as the exact string he wants to parse. His conditions do not state that word will always be the last part of the string, that just happens to be true in the example he gave. If you had the string `This sentence has the "regexp" word. This sentence doesn't have the word. This sentence does have the "regexp" word again.` your code will find no results.

Comment: @DragoonWraith: no, you are not right; I added your example to my post. As you can see all works perfect

Comment: @DragoonWraith: I'm really sorry