# Regular expression not contains a specific patterns python

Tags: python, regex

I'm working with regular expression on python then I've the followings string that I need to parse some like

```
XCT_GRUPO_INVESTIGACION_F1.sql
XCT_GRUPO_INVESTIGACION_F2.sql
XCT_GRUPO_INVESTIGACION.sql
XCS_GRUPO_INVESTIGACION.sql
```

The I need to parse all the string that has ??T, but the string not must containt somthing like `F1`,`F34`,`constrains` and others

So I've the following pattern

```
([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][tT]_([a-zA-Z]).*.(sql|SQL)$)
```

`[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][tT]_` = check  the first and second value could be whatever but I  need to be followed by `t_` or `T_`

`([a-zA-Z]).*` = any value a-z and A-Z any times

`(sql|SQL)$` = must be end with sql or SQL

I get something like

```
ICT_GRUPO_INVESTIGACION_F1.sql
ICT_GRUPO_INVESTIGACION_F2.sql
ICT_GRUPO_INVESTIGACION.sql
```

But this contains `F1`,`F?`,`constrains` and others

how can I say to the regular expression that in the expression  `([a-zA-Z]).*`  no contains `f1 | f? | others_expresion_that_Iwanna`

Comment: Can you do this without `regex`? Regexes are usualy quite slow and it will often be faster and easier to use `loop`s and `in` statements. You could easily use Pythons `endswith` method to find .sql files, and the `in` method to exclude files with the patterns you mentioned (e.g. `F1`, `F34`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regular expression should work:

```
([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][tT]_(?:(?!_F[0-9]).)*?\.(sql|SQL))
```

You may put any number of unwanted combinations here `(?!_F[0-9]|other_expression|...)`

There are following parts in the regular expression:

```
[a-zA-Z]         #match any letter
[a-zA-Z]         #match any letter
[tT]_            #match 't_' or 'T_'
(?:              #start non-capturing group
  (?!_F[0-9])    #negative lookahead, asserts that what immediately          
                 #follows the current position in the string is not _f[0-9]
  .              #match any single character
)*?              #end group, repeat it multiple times but as few as possible
\.               #match period character
(sql|SQL)        #match 'sql' or 'SQL'
```

You could find additional information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11869793/regular-expressions-find-string-without-substring), [here](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) and [here](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Looking_Ahead_and_Behind.html)