# Regex: substring in another substring

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have the following text:

```
query([[
select *
from ]]..s_Schema..[[Table
where RowNumber = n_Counter
]],{Counter = n_Counter});
```

I need to find substring `n_` that is between `([[` and `]],`.

Such a regexp: `\(\[\[[.\r\n]+n_[.\r\n]+\]\],` doesn't work.

My case seems to be opposite to this one: [Regular expressions: find string without substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11869793/regular-expressions-find-string-without-substring)

Or this: [regex match substring unless another substring matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32747887/regex-match-substring-unless-another-substring-matches)

Comment: What are you actually trying to match/find, and is there also a replacement here?

Comment: I believe you need `(?s)\[\[(?:(?!\[\[).)*?n_.*?\]\]`, but I have no idea what you *really* need to obtain in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A literal implementation of your requirement would be:

**Find:**

```
\(.*\[\[.*?(n_\w+).*\]\]
```

Your current regex has several problems, of which perhaps which stands out the most is this:

```
[.\r\n]
```

This character class doesn't do what you think; this will match one of the following three things: a literal dot, a carriage return, or a newline.  The query code you are trying to match will never match to this.

**Demo here:**

## Regex101

Answer (score 0):

Do a regular expression find like this:

- Open Find Dialog
- **Find What:** `\(\[\[\K.*(?=\]\],)`
- Check **regular expression**
- Check **. matches newline**
- Click **Find Next**

**Explanation**

- `\(\[\[\K` starts matching after `[[`
- `(?=\]\],)` is a Lookahead, it matches only if followed by `]],`